# UTF8String problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nslog

I am facing a strange problem with this `UTF8String`:

```
parentMode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
…
if(parentMode != @"Sleep")
{   
    NSLog(@"%s", [parentMode UTF8String]);      
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why do I have to do this conversion in order to log `parentMode`?
2. The log is printing `Sleep`. So how is that if is done anyway?

Comment: its simple, why the log show Sleep ? if its Sleep, the if statement is not true and there should be a log ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare strings using the normal relational operators, you must use:

```
if (![parentMode isEqualToString:@"Sleep"])
{
    NSLog (@"%@", parentMode);
}
```

You may want to check that `parentMode` is not `nil` before using that method, however. You don't need to use the `UTF8String` method, you can log the string directly using the `%@` format specifier. If this is not working, then there is something very important that you are omitting from the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

To log the string, you can write:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", parentMode);
```

Using the `%@` placeholder, there's not need to convert it back to UTF-8.

This probably also explains why the *if* statement works.

*Update:*

You should compare string with `isEqualToString:`

```
[parentMode isEqualToString: @"Sleep"]
```

Comment: its not right. if i log with @ its crashes all time. and i have tried in so many ways. another thing is, why the if condition is made if the value is sleep ???

Comment: Your string comparison isn't correct. You should use isEqualToString: to compare strings. And it shouldn't crash with the @"%@" format string. If it does, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing the integers then you have to use the syntax whatever you have used in the post.But when you compare the strings use this.

```
if (![parentMode isEqualToString:@"Sleep"])
{
    NSLog (@"%@", parentMode);
}
```